# Need to calculate difference between two timestamps for every empid

Tags: excel, excel-formula, timestamp

I have data given to me in excel like this.The data shows different employees calling. An employee might have called more than once on same or different days.

```
empid       call_time_starts
1234         7/1/16  9:00
5678         7/21/16 0:00
1234         7/19/16 3:00
7687         7/21/16 6:00
1234         7/17/16 6:00
```

I want result like

```
empid       call_time_starts   no._of_days
1234         7/1/16  9:00        
5678         7/21/16 0:00
1234         7/19/16 3:00       18 days
5678         7/28/16 6:00        7 days
```

I need to find out the number of days for an empid since the last call.
like 1234 id had called first on 7/1/16 9:00 and is now calling after 18days on
7/19/16 3:00 . I need to find that 18 days. 
I can use r or excel for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DAYS()` function is all you need to find the number of days between two timestamps.

If you want to automatically find the days since the previous timestamp for that ID, then try something like this in C2

```
=DAYS(B2,INDEX(B$1:B2,MAX((A$1:A1=A2)*ROW(A$1:A1))))
```

assuming your `empid` is in column A and `call_time_starts` is in column B.

Comment: Could you help me understand the formua. I got the output  :)

Comment: `B2` is the end date. The `INDEX` formula looks in column B for the last row (`MAX` row number) above the current row `n` (the range `A$1:A(n-1)`) such that the `empid` is the same as the one on the current row (`A$1:A(n-1)=A(n)`). The equality evaluates to 0 or 1, thus eliminating the rows numbers where the ID doesn't match.

Comment: when you write B$1 you have not included column headers right? B$1 refers to first date in b column right?

Comment: No, you need to start at row 1, headers or not, or else the index won't align with the ROW.